# Does a person who wets or soils himself during lashes still receive the kapparah?

Tags: maseches-makos, kaparah-atonement, lashes-malkos

The punishment of lashes serves as a *kapparah* (atonement) for a person's aveirah.

- 1) **The Sefer HaChinuch** ([Mitzvah # 594](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.594.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes that the reason for the mitzvah of lashes was to penalize the sinner in this world so that he should change his ways and still merit a desirable afterlife.
- 2) **Rambam** [Hilchos Sanhedrin 17:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.17.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)- Whenever a person sins and is lashed, he returns to his original state of *kashrus*.
- see also: [**Rashi** on Sanhedrin 10a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.10a.12?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.10a.12.1&lang2=bi) who writes how lashes are like one of the 4 types of capital punishment (ie each which provides *kapparah*)

### However

The *mishnah* on [Makkos 22b](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.22b.13?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) states:

> נתקלקל בין בריעי בין במים פטור רבי יהודה אומר האיש בריעי והאשה במים:
>
> If one sullies himself, whether with excrement or with urine, he is exempt [from further lashes]. Rabbi Yehuda says: the man is exempted with excrement, and the woman is exempted with urine.
>
> expanded on [Makkos 23a](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.23a.18?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)

... and the **Rambam** elaborates further in [Hilchos Sanhedrin 17:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.17.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> מִי שֶׁאֲמָדוּהוּ וּכְשֶׁהִתְחִיל לִלְקוֹת נִתְקַלְקֵל מִכֹּחַ הַהַכָּאָה בֵּין בְּרֵיעִי בֵּין בְּמֵימֵי רַגְלַיִם אֵין מַכִּין אוֹתוֹ יוֹתֵר שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים כה ג) "וְנִקְלָה אָחִיךָ לְעֵינֶיךָ" כֵּיוָן שֶׁנִּקְלָה פָּטוּר
>
> When it was estimated that a person could bear a specific number of lashes, they began lashing him and he became distressed due to the power of the blows and either defecated or urinated, he is not given any more lashes. This is derived from Deuteronomy 25:3: "and your brother will be degraded before your eyes." Since he was distressed, he is absolved.

### Question:

I understand how wetting or soiling oneself is a fulfillment of "and your brother will be degraded before your eyes" and is enough to cut the session short.

But can it ***really*** be that a person receives the *kapparah* for lashes by wetting or soiling themself?
How?

Comment: Seriously, we don't deal with Kapparah, we only deal with what we're are authorized to do. So if we stone someone, that's because we're commanded to do so, with no connection with the Kapparah that comes from G-d. Similarly, with lashes - we do what we ought to do, and G-d decides whether the person is forgiven or not.

Comment: In other words, you're asking whether פטור is פטור אבל אסור (still needs some Kapporah) or פטור לגמרי (like wetting completes the lashes)?

Comment: Perhaps the very fact that they wet/soiled themselves indicates that the one getting lashed had a sufficient amount of pain/discomfort, to attain kapparah.

Comment: maybe the wetting or soiling achieves being 'degraded' (or at least complete it)

Comment: @user9806 right I know wetting/soiling oneself means they're exempt, but would we say "exempt" is the same thing as "fulfilled obligation" (ie receiving the lashes)?

Comment: @hazoriz user9806 also suggests that, see above comment. Makkos 23a https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.23a.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en  It's unclear if "exempt" would be the same as ""fulfilled obligation"

Comment: @AlBerko yep am asking that-  while wetting/soiling oneself makes him exempt, does he still need *kapparah* or the act of wetting/soiling oneself not only exempts but also means he's achieved full atonement

Comment: @alicht i think our ideas are slightly different, in other words his kaboro is achived by bing hit and being degraded (by the hit itself not afterwords), for the sin, this degradation which and happen in 3 ways 1. by 39 hits, 2. by the maximum hit he can take, or 3. Even by one hit if it couses him to soil himself on the spot

Comment: @alicht : what is the difference between "exempt" and having received "kapparah", in practical terms? If being exempt means one doesn't get punishment (as the Mishna there says, he is exempt from kares), why does he need the kapparah?

Comment: The hit isself is degrading that is what couses the kapara, (a jew that sined has caused the disgrace of G-d Almighty (chilul hashem) for the community to restore G-d Almightys dignity they need to disgrase the sinner , this disgrase is a kaporos for the person himself to since he clearly, visably takes his disgrase/sin back)

Comment: A hit (less then what is needed, to be considered a discras by itself) plus soil = all the hits nessesery

Comment: @hazoriz interesting- so (if I understand correctly) what I think you & user9806 are suggesting is that the main *yesod* of receiving the kapparah for lashes is for one "be degraded."  Be it receiving the full 39 lashes or receiving 4 lashes + soiling themself- in either case the person is considered degraded and thus both receive the kapparah

Comment: @user9806 ^^ above

Comment: @alicht yes that is how i see it, but i need to correct myself, it seems that he should be degraded but, not  severely degraded ( https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.25.3 ) 40 hits makes him severly degraded so he needs less than that (39 or as much as he can take), soiling himself makes him severely degraded so one can be sure that he had enough (but this is only if the soiling had to do with the hit)